# How to combine List and State Monad in Haskell

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

I want to basically map over a list and at the same time carry along some state. I figured combining the list and state monads might get me there. I tried a few things and figured out that I likely need to use `ListT` for that. As a simplified version of my actual problem, imagine that I want to implement the `sum` function, while also returning a modified version of the original list. This or similar is what I imagined it would have to look like:

```
sum' :: ListT (State Int) Int
sum' = do
    lift $ put 0
    x <- [1,2,3]
    lift $ modify (+x)
    return $ x + 1
```

What I don't get yet is how the syntax of the regular list monad translates to the ListT monad. I cannot simply do `x <- [1,2,3]`, since on the right side of the arrow, type `ListT (State Int) t0` is expected. `x <- return [1,2,3]` compiles (as in keeps the compiler from complaining about this line) but gets me the whole list put into x, instead of each element.

How do I get this working?

Comment: Do you want `ssum xs = execState (traverse (modify . (+)) xs) 0`?

Comment: Unfortunately, whenever anyone talks about `ListT`, you really have to ask "which one?" because there are several very different versions that behave very differently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    x <- ListT $ return [1,2,3]
```

or

```
    x <- msum $ return <$> [1,2,3]
```

will do the trick.

- `ListT . return` just injects a list structure-awarely into a list-transformed monad stack.
- `msum` uses the fact that `ListT` is the transformer mapping a monad to the free `MonadPlus` monoid over it.